# Theorem number section wise when there is no subsection

Tags: newtheorem

I am using article class.
There is no any chapter. It has some sections only.

In my first section there are five subsections.
I want the Theorem and Definition numbers as per section wise, like Theorem 1.2.4 or Definition 1.5.2, etc.

In further sections there are no subsections.
In the second section since there is no subsection. So here I want like, Theorem 2.1 or Definition 2.4, etc that is without subsection number.

Please suggest the suitable commands.

Comment: I suggest to accept answers to your other questions first, instead of piling up questions and 'exploiting' the knowledge of users here. `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and `\counterwithin{theorem}{section}` in the relevant section should do, assuming that the counter is named `theorem`.

Comment: Ok, definitely I will do the same. I was not aware of this.

Comment: Sir, In the Second section the first Definition is appearing Definition 2.7 instead of Definition 2.1. And  onward third section the Definition is right i.e. Definition 3.1.

Comment: Well, unless you show a compilable document there's only guessing around here.It's up to you to provide this MWE

Answer (score 3):

You can define a new theorem `Definition` with the counter depending on `section` and `subsection` and the output of the counter `\theDefinition` use `\thesection` as long as `subsection` counter is less than 1 and `\thesubsection` otherwise:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}[subsection]% Counter `Definition` depends on `subsection` …
\counterwithin*{Definition}{section}% … and also on `section`.

\renewcommand*{\theDefinition}{% Output of `Definition` counter:
  \ifnum\value{subsection}<1 % if `subsection` counter is less than 1 (mostly `\subsection` not yet used in this `\section`)
    \thesection% show \thesection, e.g., 1
  \else% otherwise
    \thesubsection% show \thesubsection, e.g., 1.1
  \fi
  .\arabic{Definition}% followed by "." and Arabic number of Definition
}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}
\begin{Definition}[Definition on section level]
\blindtext
\end{Definition}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{Definition}[Definition in subsection level]
\blindtext
\end{Definition}

\section{Second test section}
\begin{Definition}[Second theorem on section level]
\blindtext
\end{Definition}
\subsection{Second test subsection}
\begin{Definition}[Second theorem in subsection level]
\blindtext
\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: result with Definitions on section or subsection level]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an abstraction of the procedure, very useful if you eventually change your mind about the numbering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse,chngcntr}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newtheorembysubsection}{mom}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {
    \newtheorem{#1}{#3}[subsection]
    \cs_set:cpn { the#1 } { \thesection. \deepesh_subsection: \arabic{#1} }
    \counterwithin*{#1}{section}
   }
   {
    \newtheorem{#1}[#2]{#3}
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \deepesh_subsection:
 {
  \int_compare:nT { \value{subsection}>0 } { \arabic{subsection}. }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtheorembysubsection{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorembysubsection{definition}[theorem]{Definition} % could be \newtheorem

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem, numbered 1.1
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
A definition, numbered 1.2
\end{definition}

\subsection{Test subsection}

\begin{definition}
A definition, numbered 1.1.1
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem, numbered 1.1.2
\end{theorem}

\section{Test second section}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem, numbered 2.1
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Test subsection}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem, numbered 2.1.1
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

In case you decide to number theorems by section (as it should be, I find this scheme quite complex for the reader), you just change `\newtheorembysubsection` into `\newtheorem`, possibly adding a trailing `[section]` if needed.

[image]